# WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS Performance Mode

Tags: performance, cpu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is there a way to set WSL2 Ubuntu 22 to performance mode? I know the original version of the OS you can just set it to performance mode but I'm not sure how to do it through WSL2.

When I run

```
grep "cpu MHz" /proc/cpuinfo
```

It shows

```
cpu MHz         : 3192.001
```

cpu MHz         : 3192.001
cpu MHz         : 3192.001
cpu MHz         : 3192.001
cpu MHz         : 3192.001
cpu MHz         : 3192.001
cpu MHz         : 3192.001
cpu MHz         : 3192.001
cpu MHz         : 3192.001
cpu MHz         : 3192.001
cpu MHz         : 3192.001
cpu MHz         : 3192.001

But task manager on Windows shows about 4.2 GHz.

I'm wondering if WSL2 is able to take advantage of Intel turbo.

Comment: Looks like it always just reports the base cpu speed, no matter what speed the cores are actually running.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. <sup>*A.k.a. "No, but I could always be wrong."*</sup>

Under WSL2, Ubuntu is running as a container/namespace inside a managed virtual machine.  That "managed" part means that we, as end-users, don't have much control over it directly.  Even if it was running in a virtual machine, I'm not sure there's any hypervisor that would allow you to control the CPU at that level.  It's the host operating system that has to handle that.

While I haven't tried this, it might be possible to change the Windows process priority for WSL/Ubuntu.  In Windows 11 22H2, in the Task Manager, you can choose the *Details* tab, right-click on `wsl.exe`, and use *Set priority* to select from:

- Realtime
- High
- Above Normal
- Normal (default)
- Below Normal
- Low

It would be interesting to hear what direct results you might see (or not) in Ubuntu performance after changing this.